# FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie is not setting cookie in WebResponse Cookie Collection

Tags: c#, formsauthentication

I have a website that uses forms authentication and calls `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie` when the user has been validated, i.e `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, false)`.

I am currently creating HttpWebRequests and calling the website with the username and password and although the credentials pass validation - the response does not have any cokkies in its cookie collection.

The HTTP request/response code is below:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) CreatePostRequest(baseAddress, postParameters);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

the code gets the response just fine and while debugging I can see the credentials being validated ok and the FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user, false) being called.

When I check the response cookie collection the count is 0. Can anyone help me understand why this is.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You'll most probably find cookies in `response.Headers["Set-Cookie"]`. You can store these cookies in an instance of `CookieContainer` class simply by `CookieContainer.SetCookies(baseAddress, response.Headers["Set-Cookie"]` and then using this `CookieContainer` instance in your subsequent requests. Hope this helps.